# how to extract from cURL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, api, extract

I have an API that gives me results in this format:

```
{1 item
"items":[3 items
0:{12 items
"sugar_g":0
"fiber_g":0
"serving_size_g":396.893
"sodium_mg":246
"name":"prime rib"
"potassium_mg":720
"fat_saturated_g":43.7
"fat_total_g":107.7
"calories":1383.1
"cholesterol_mg":323
"protein_g":88.6
"carbohydrates_total_g":0
}
1:{12 items
"sugar_g":3.6
"fiber_g":2.3
"serving_size_g":100
"sodium_mg":587
"name":"pizza"
"potassium_mg":217
"fat_saturated_g":4.5
"fat_total_g":9.8
"calories":262.9
"cholesterol_mg":16
"protein_g":11.4
"carbohydrates_total_g":32.9
}
2:{12 items
"sugar_g":1.4
"fiber_g":1.5
"serving_size_g":100
"sodium_mg":329
"name":"mashed potatoes"
"potassium_mg":47
"fat_saturated_g":0.7
"fat_total_g":4.2
"calories":114
"cholesterol_mg":0
"protein_g":2
"carbohydrates_total_g":16.8
}
]
}
```

how can I extract this data so that I can store them in variables?

i have tried this, but give me just one result

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($response,true);
 foreach($jsonDecoded['items'] as $item){
   $sugar = $item['sugar_g'];
   $calories = $item['calories'];
   $name = $item['name'];
   $serving_size = $item['serving_size_g'];
 }
```

what I'm trying to achieve is I can extract all Sugars, Calories, Name and etc

Comment: What format was this before you printed it? Was it JSON? In any case, now that you have an object, you just need to to `loop` `items` and then access the sub-information. What have you tried so far?

Comment: it looks like JSON but this is no valid JSON, this looks like a copy from the developer tools or the console, isnt'it ?

Comment: This is the API code:

 $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/nutrition?query=One%20large%20BBQ%20Chicken%20Pizza",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
 echo $response;
}

Comment: Yes, that API appears to return JSON. So decode it, and then var_dump the resulting object if you are not sure what structure you are dealing with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass true in `json_decode()` function it will be array so you need to access as array and there is a multiple data so you need loop.

```
 $jsonDecoded = json_decode($response,true);
 foreach(jsonDecoded['items'] as $item){
   echo $item['sugar_g'];
 }
```

Comment: i got Notice: Undefined index: sugar_g in Line

Comment: do you need to read all items?

Comment: maybe 6-7 items, like Name, calories, carbs, fats, protein, sugar, serving_size_g

Comment: edited answer it should work

Comment: how can I access all the items??